# Oracle DB to EF not working correctly for NUMBER(2,0)

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework

I have a table column defined like this:

```
ENTRY_STATUS NUMBER(2, 0)
```

And in my EntityFramework class the respective field is defined like this:

```
[Column("ENTRY_STATUS")]
public int Status { get; set; }
```

When checking the value to get an entry it works perfectly fine:

```
var order = testDbContext.Orders.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Status > 1);
```

But when I check the `order` entity after this statement it is always zero:

```
if (order != null)
{
    if (order.Status == 3) //Always Zero!!!
    { //Do something... 
    }
}
```

What went wrong here with my definitions? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a caching problem.
Following article helped me: http://codethug.com/2016/02/19/Entity-Framework-Cache-Busting/

I don't know if it is an EF bug that the query itself (`o => o.Status > 1`) recognizes the change in the database but than retrieves the data from the cache, which can be different.
Anyway, adding AsNoTracking() solved the problem:

```
var order = testDbContext.Orders.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(o => o.Status > 1);
```

Comment: Happy to hear it's solved. Good work with the research.

Answer (score 3):

The Oracle Database Column for a .Net `Int32` should be: `NUMBER(9, 0)`

As per the [Conversion Table](https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/ODPNT/entityDataTypeMapping.htm#ODPNT8467):

```
+------------------------------+------------------+-----------------+
|         Oracle Type          | Default EDM Type | Custom EDM Type |
+------------------------------+------------------+-----------------+
| Number(1,0)                  | Int16            | bool            |
| Number(2,0) to Number(3,0)   | Int16            | byte            |
| Number(4,0)                  | Int16            | Int16           |
| Number(5,0)                  | Int16            | Int32           |
| Number(6,0) to Number(9,0)   | Int32            | Int32           |
| Number(10,0)                 | Int32            | Int64           |
| Number(11,0) to Number(18,0) | Int64            | Int64           |
| Number(19,0)                 | Int64            | Decimal         |
+------------------------------+------------------+-----------------+
```

**Edit:**

I found a way you can force the `Number(2,0)` to be translated to a byte in the App.Config *for Database-First approach*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
  </connectionStrings>
  <oracle.dataaccess.client>
    <settings>
      <add name="bool" value="edmmapping number(1,0)" />
      <add name="byte" value="edmmapping number(3,0)" />
      <add name="int16" value="edmmapping number(4,0)" />
```

REF: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ODPNT/entityDataTypeMapping.htm#ODPNT8300

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have influence on the database. How can I fix this on my side (Entity Framework)?

Comment: The column datatype doesn't support it, are you using a Database-First approach?

Comment: Yes. I use Db First approach

Answer (score 1):

The query

```
var order = testDbContext.Orders.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Status > 1);
```

is executed on the server so it returns the excepted result.

Then the `Order` entity is created and EF tries to map a value of `ENTRY_STATUS` column from `number(2,0)` to `Int32` which is not possible.

In my point of view the best solution is to change a type of `Status` to `Int16`

```
[Column("ENTRY_STATUS")]
public Int16 Status { get; set; }
```

Comment: he old could use short (Int16)

Comment: I tried it with short and Int16 but still have the same problem

Comment: @Palmi Did you also try byte? What kind of oracle data provider do you use?

Comment: I use Devart dotconnect for Oracle