# Entity Framework scaffold the wrong type

Tags: c#, oracle11g, entity-framework-core, byte

On our Oracle 11g table, we have a column with the type Number(2,0).

During the scaffolding process, Entity Framework converted to Number(2,0) to byte.

```
[Column("RETRIES", TypeName = "NUMBER(2)")]
public byte Retries { get; set; }
```

The problem occurs when user enter -1 in the column.  Oracle accepted, but C# freaks out, because -1 is not a valid byte type.

I tried to use int instead of byte, but Entity Framework still uses OracleDataReader.GetByte() to retrieve the data.

```
[Column("RETRIES", TypeName = "NUMBER(2)")]
public int Retries { get; set; }
```

Does anyone have a solution for this?  Thanks!

Comment: never used a byte col, but what happens if you use `sbyte`?

Comment: @PatrickBeynio...that didn't work either, because EF (Oracle) keeps using GetByte()

Comment: Your problem has been solved in another thread. Please [refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46589929/oracle-db-to-ef-not-working-correctly-for-number2-0) to it